# using custom init method in iphone -identifying a leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, init

For one of my custom classes, I have defined a method called initialize to set some instance variables at the same time as the init. The code is below. The analyzer tool is reporting a leak in viewDidLoad on the line with [[Employee alloc]..
Since I am releasing the variable in the dealloc, I thought that this should be fine..what could be the issue? thanks in advance.

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    Employee *employee;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
if(employee ==nil) 
   employee = [[Employee alloc] initialize:@"John"];    

if (![employee.entityName isEqualToString:@"Test"]) { //The leak is reported here for object allocated above
    ///...
}

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    employee = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
  [employee release];

}

//In the Employee class
-(id) initialize:(NSString*) name{
    self = [super init];

    self.entityName = name;


    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewDidUnLoad` you need to `release` employee before it gets set to `nil`.  Else in your `dealloc`, you are just releasing `nil`.

ie

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [employee release];
    employee = nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I am still not able to remove the reported leak. wonder why:(